# Bootstrap glyphicons not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

When I run an HTML file from file system (right click and open in browser), everything works fine, but when I run it through localhost, browser does not properly load fonts. Tested in Chrome and Firefox. Both of these browsers send 2 requests for woff and ttf font files on the same pageload.

Here is the demonstration of the problem. Fonts are not loaded properly, and I think different fonts are displayed on different browser. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

[image]

Firefox network tab.

[image]

Comment: Supply the code as well, It'll help in debugging.

Comment: There is no special code. Everything is in bootstrap.css

Comment: What shows the console? By the way, there are many options better like fontawesome

Comment: did you change the font url in css as bs tutorial says?

Comment: The problem is not bootstrap vs fontawesome. The problem is what are these different behaviours in different contexts.

Comment: Don't be naive, you want the rest of us to help you, we need to see what you've done.

Comment: I know, that's why I just write a comment, not an answer. I just answer your "by the way" with another one.

Comment: When a use a font URL, as mentioned in firefox network tab, and paste in address bar, I properly starts download of the font file and gives saving options. In that save box, it properly shows file size. However in the above list, it is showing 0 KB filesize for each font.

Comment: I cannot upload console's screenshot, but fount "Cross site request blocked" and "Cross site request not allowed" for all font files. I have static resources on different domain on localhost. What is this error?

Comment: Your error is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771113/bootstrap-glyphicons-not-working#comment42122544_26771113), your issue is in relation to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

You'll have to add something like this into your `.htaccess` file

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
```

Or in php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

The `*` flag allows access from **all** origins.

You can only supply `*`, `null` or fully qualified domains, like `google.com`.

Comment: Thanks Darren. I have another question. Why are other files like css, images and js are loading cross origin properly? On further inspection, I found that browser is only sending "Origin" request header for font files.

Comment: Any help in this regard?

Comment: Hey mate, are you accessing the scripts from a sub directory? I.e. cdn.yourwebsite.com?